# find lowest value for each element given some intervals and its values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was thinking about this:

A market has `n` products and `m` sellers. For each seller `k`, we have triplet  `(i,j,p)`: it means the seller selling the products numbered `i, i+1, .., j` each at price `p`.

**Goal:**
Find lowest price for each product (1..n) in the market. You can assume price of a product as infinity for which no seller exist.

**Example:**
`n=4, m=3` and the 3 triplets are `(1,3,4), (2,3,2), (3,4,1)`. So the lowest values for products `(1..4)` will are: `(4, 2, 1, 1)`.

The `O(nm)` solution is trivial. We can use binary indexed tree for range updates and point query in `O(n+ mlogn)`.

Can anyone suggest an easier method (may be with sorting) in `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: Seems the same solution as [Christmas Visit Nightmare!](http://www.sklivvz.com/posts/christmas-visits-nightmare), which is [here](http://www.sklivvz.com/posts/answer-for-christmas-visit-nightmare)

Comment: @Sklivvz , i think it is not the problem like job scheduling.

Comment: I'm confused by your question... If `m` is small, then it's automatically `O(nlogn)`. If `m` is big, then it has to appear somewhere in the big O... you will at least need to read all the `m` sellers once, right?

Comment: m<=100000, n<=100000  @ WhatsUp and I want any of these solution:  nlogn, mlogn, mlogm, nlogm

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess in O(M*(logN+logM)) and then answer each query in O(logN) using Segment tree, which is described here [Algorithm Gym :: Data structures - Codeforces.](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/15729)

For your problem:

- For each interval, update the corresponding nodes in Segment tree. (Note that here you need to use Lazy propagation, which is also described in the above link)
- After all update is done, you can use Segment tree to answer the queries.